# (How) can residents of Storia travel between regions?

Tags: no-thank-you-evil

In the [*No Thank You, Evil!*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/27391/no-thank-you-evil) family roleplaying game, PCs can travel to the four different regions of Storia* by means of gates located in the players' bedrooms. However, it is clear that residents of Storia cannot use these gates:

> The gateways are guarded by magical barriers. Only characters and their companions can travel back and forth.

This idea is further suggested by the Map of Storia, which shows a rift between each of the four regions, linked only by a house (presumably the player's).

However, in the companion story to the game *Lucy Lawful and the Awful Waffle*, the eponymous heroine of the story, a resident of Behind the Bookshelf, in order to appease the gluttonous Mr Smigglesmack claims:

> Look, Mister Smigglesmack, let's make a deal.
>   I know a baker who'll really appeal.
>   She runs Hex Kitchen and she makes the best treats.
>   Waffles and cookies and all kinds of sweets.

She is referring to the Kitchen Witch, a resident of Into the Closet, and the follow-on adventure assumes the PCs will be able to arrange for the Kitchen Witch to provide Mr Smigglesmack with tasty baked treats every day. But unless the PCs were to deliver them, how would this be possible**? Also, how does Lucy Lawful know the Kitchen Witch in the first place? Or are there ways that characters from one region of Storia can travel to another region, without going through one of the aforementioned gateways?

As far as I can tell the rulebooks are silent on this, but maybe I missed something or the designers explained it during the Kickstarter or elsewhere. I need this information before my children ask me!

---

* Behind the Bookshelf, Into the Closet, Out of the Window, and Under the Bed

** I'm assuming Mister Smigglesmack lives Behind the Bookshelf, though as far as I can tell this is not explicitly stated anywhere. See [my other question about where Mr Smigglesmack lives.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93834/where-does-mister-smigglesmack-live-and-what-level-is-he) Even if he lives Into the Closet, then the problem of how Lucy Lawful knows the Kitchen Witch still remains.

Answer (score 3):

I kind of wondered about that myself.  If Shanna Germain or Monte Cook have issued any particular declaration on this, it would actually surprise me.

Both of the Cypher System games I have - this one and Numenera - tend to provide a lot of *flavor* in their setting descriptions and leave you to fill in the *details* however you see fit.  This is actually a wonderful approach, IMO, but I can see how people who like things more nailed-down might find it irksome.

I think the (perhaps unsatisfying) answer here is "whatever you need it to be".  Need an easy way for things to get from one place to another?  Maybe there are established doorways that lead between the realms.  Need it to be very difficult or even impossible for most?  Maybe the only way to do it is by way of a certain spell or a magical gateway that only opens once every 3 years and almost no one knows about it.

My answer to that question for my personal NTYE incarnation is "it's almost certainly possible, but it's difficult and not widely known".  Further, I'm not even sure most denizens of one particular realm know the other *realms* exist.  I don't have anything more concrete than that, because, so far, I haven't needed it.  If your kids ask about it, "you don't know" is always acceptable answer.  Let 'em have some mystery.  And you only really need to *have* an answer if it's relevant to the story.

But that's just my take.  Maybe you want a setting that's much more unified.  In that case, you'd probably flavor yours differently.  I think they creators intend details like that to be "season to taste".