# Where does Mister Smigglesmack live and what is his level?

Tags: no-thank-you-evil

In *Lucy Lawful and the Awful Waffle*, the companion story to the family roleplaying game [*No Thank You, Evil!*](https://rpggeek.com/rpg/27391/no-thank-you-evil), we are introduced to Mr Smigglesmack, the antagonist of the story who is revealed to have stolen the Awful Waffle.

However, despite the fact that he is mentioned in the follow up adventure at the back of *Lucy Lawful and the Awful Waffle*, and despite the fact his picture appears on the game's box, as far as I can tell we are not told what region of Storia he lives in (presumably either Behind the Bookshelf where Lucy Lawful lives, or Into the Closet where the Kitchen Witch lives - see [my other question about whether they can travel between regions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/93833/how-can-residents-of-storia-travel-between-regions)), and we are not given his level.

Have I missed something, or was this information given elsewhere by the designers, perhaps in the original Kickstarter? I want to run the *Lucy Lawful* adventure with my kids, and would like to know these facts to play Mister Smigglesmack properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was curious about this as well, so I sent a tweet to Monte Cook games and got a response back that is as follows:

> Hi there! We didn't put him in a certain area, because we wanted the Guide to be able to place him anywhere that felt the most fun. Maybe he has houses in multiple areas of Storia :D We also didn't list a level, so Guides are free to use their best judgement for their story!
>
> — Monte Cook Games (@MonteCookGames) [May 31, 2019](https://twitter.com/MonteCookGames/status/1134481643585048576?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

So basically it is up to the person running the game to determine for themselves according to how they want the story to go.